# Need a help on override Createdate Salesforce Instance

Tags: salesforce, validationrules

When importing data into sales-force Org from another Sales-force Org data, In this process Create date controlled by sales-force system. but create date is playing very important role on new instance in following actions,

1.few of Formula field values are depending on Create date

2.Validation Rules  condition compares field value should be greater than create date and it is not allowing to create new Data

Can anyone help me to Overriding created date when importing records

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open a ticket to the salesforce support and request for "Create Audit Field" permissions.
More details can be found by the following links:

http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000003799&language=en_US
http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2009/04/27/modifying-salesforcecom-system-fields/